# How to change the wordpress default logo from the Admin?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Wordpress Logo]

I want to create a custom logo so I need change the default logo of the wordpress logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the function (inserted into functions.php) which will correctly override the admin logo:

```
/**
* customize the admin logo that appears in the header
* http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/adding-a-custom-dashboard-logo-in-wordpress-for-       branding/
* @author Paul Bredenberg
*/
 
function htx_custom_logo() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon { 
background-image: url(' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/images/dashboard-logo.png) !important; 
background-position: 0 0;
}
#wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
background-position: 0 0;
}   
 </style>
';
}

 //hook into the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'htx_custom_logo');
```

HTH!

Comment: I also had to do #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo>.ab-item .ab-icon:before{ content: none} because wp logo remained there

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great plugin for this, and much more. [White Label CMS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/)

Answer (score 1):

I did few arrangement:

 - support the fullscreen mode

 - use the favicon of the site so it is automatically customized for multisites, and you can put some default image if there is no favicon)

I put "width: 12px" to have a square shape for the favicon cover background

If it can help someone here is the code :

```
function my_custom_admin_logo() {
    echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {content:none;}
            #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > a {
                background-image: url(' . get_site_icon_url() . ') !important;
                background-size: cover !important;
            }
            #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon {width: 12px;}
            @media screen and (max-width:782px){ #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon {width: 46px;} }
            a.edit-post-fullscreen-mode-close.has-icon {
                background-image: url(' . get_site_icon_url() . ');
                background-size: cover;
            }
            .edit-post-fullscreen-mode-close.has-icon > svg > path { display: none;}
        </style>
    ';
}
//hook into the administrative header output
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_custom_admin_logo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
    body.login div#login h1 a {
        background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/site-login-logo.png);
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dashboard logo to custom logo with this code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');

function my_custom_logo() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
</style>
';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sunny's answer only overrides the icon of the item. If you want to delete the item completely you can do this:

```
function htx_custom_logo() {
  echo '
    <style type="text/css">
      #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo>.ab-item { 
       display:none;
      }
    </style>
  ';
}

 //hook into the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'htx_custom_logo');
```