# Can you add a custom dashboard logo on Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to replace the Wordpress logo in the dashboard on the top left? Where there's a 'W'

Is this possible?

Comment: Short answer: yes! How? First hit Google: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/adding-a-custom-dashboard-logo-in-wordpress-for-branding/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the wordpress default logo from the Admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922335/how-to-change-the-wordpress-default-logo-from-the-admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, 2 ways:

1. Plugin: [White Label CMS wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/)
2. Via code:

> First you need to save your custom logo as `custom-logo.png` file on
>   your computer. It needs to be exactly `16 x 16px` in dimensions.
>
> Once you have your custom logo ready, you need to upload it to
>   `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images` folder using FTP. If your theme
>   does not have an images folder, then you need to create it.
>
> After uploading you custom logo image, simply add this code to your
>   theme’s `functions.php` file or a site-specific plugin.

```
function wpb_custom_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
    #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {
    background-image: url(' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/custom-logo.png) !important;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
    background-position: 0 0;
    }
    </style>
    ';
}

//hook into the administrative header output
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpb_custom_logo');
```

You can find more information here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/adding-a-custom-dashboard-logo-in-wordpress-for-branding/

Comment: Dat copy/paste tho :D

Comment: Unless you share source.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wpb_custom_logo() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {
background-image: url(' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/custom-logo.png) !important;
background-position: 0 0;
color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
background-position: 0 0;
}
</style>
';
}

//hook into the administrative header output
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpb_custom_logo');
```

add this code to your functions.php after uploading your logo (16x16)