# How to delete logo Wordpress from wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

How can i DELETE Wordpress logo from wp-admin(screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1fzB.png)) **?** i tried every code from here: [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922335/how-to-change-the-wordpress-default-logo-from-the-admin) but it doesn't working.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1fzB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in functions.php of your active theme.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999 );
 function remove_wp_logo( $wp_admin_bar ) {
 $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );
}
```

Comment: Yes :) WP logo in my wp-admin was deleted for everyone users(it's ok) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link hope you are easily understand
[Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes)